# Errors using alaouy/Youtube package with Laravel 5.4 for fetching videos from Youtube

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am using alaouy/Youtube package on Laravel 5.4. It's fetching videos from Youtube  but I am getting errors.

```
// view
@extends('welcome') 
    @section('content')
       <ul>
           @foreach($videos as $data)
                <div class="well">
                    {{ $data->id->videoId}}
               </div>
           @endforeach
       </ul>
   @endsection

// controller
$videos = Youtube::search($search);
return view('search',compact('videos'));
```

I am able to get access to all the data in the object except `{{$data->id->videoId}}`

```
// Error
Undefined property: stdClass::$videoId (View: 
C:\Users\derrick\testyoutubeapi\resources\views\search.blade.php)
```

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, but when i dd(videos) in the controller it videoId in the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not receiving the required data so you are getting the error message of not defined property.

in other words, you are requesting videoId field which is not there for some of kinds like **playlist** (playlistId), or maybe a **channel** (channelId)

so your problem solution should be just making your code in the view to  check if there is a field that is called videoId or no before the query:

```
           @foreach($videos as $data)
             @if(isset($data->id->videoId)) // field available?
            <div class="well">
                {{ $data->id->videoId}}
             @endif // end if
           </div>
       @endforeach
```

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, but when i dd(videos) in the controller it videoId in the object

Comment: ALL of the videos must have videoIds, the problem with the items in the search results that dont, so if you got 4 videos and 2 channels, all the 4 videos will give videoId but because of the channels, foreach will get null ,, which causes the problem

Comment: if you can post your dd($videos) here i'll explain further

Comment: @derrick and please make sure you are editing the question .. not the answer :)